# Serving Dockerized Static Sites

Tags: docker, nginx, deployment, devops

**Question**: What is the convention for serving static websites though NGINX, in a containerized environment?

**Hypothetical**: You have a bare metal host with NGINX and three static sites, each with their own folder in `var/www`. The usual NGINX rules for serving the appropriate files are in place. The goal is to dockerize NGINX and put the static sites *somewhere* other than the host machine.

**Options**: Putting the static site artifacts in the NGINX container creates a coupling between applications which I'd like to avoid. This leaves a solution of creating a container for each static site and mounting the volumes from the NGINX container-which feels a little off to me.

Answer (score 1):

Good going, seems you already know the basics on how you are going to serve static content from NGINX.

To add a few cents. Keeping files in a container is not an option as the container is a stateless entity. Every change in the static file will require you to rebuild
the container which is not scalable at all. so the options we are left with are discussed below.

So to answer your queries, majority of the dockerized application used in production spin up multiple docker containers who is serving content from individual host's directory.

another practice is having a single docker instance with multiple file directories mounted to it.
Let's say \website1 mount to hosts /var/www/website1 and so on...

Both approaches have pros and cons of their own, the deployment will certainly depend on your requirement.

But going by something called principles of container app design it is a good practice to go with approach no. 1
[Container Design Priciples](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/03/principles-of-container-app-design/)

Being said that one of what we have discussed is mounting the host volume to docker which is highly scalable for common practice in IT deployment.
There is another option of mounting the s3 volume to the container (fuse) and using it as if those directories exist on the host's machine.

More info on same:
[Mounting s3 bucket to Docker](https://medium.com/spritle-software/mounting-an-s3-bucket-using-fuse-1c1d3cc594c4)

Hope this helps. Thanks.